# Laptop-shaped device serving as I/O for a desktop PC

Tags: laptop, desktop, wireless

When I do computer work at home I prefer to lie down but two factors cause me inconvenience: the weight of the laptop and the need to charge it often.

So I wonder if there is a laptop-shaped device that has the I/O of a normal laptop but actually connects to a desktop which performs all the computations. It presumably would be lighter and would not have to be charged as often.

Comment: I would buy a cheap android tablet with a good display, and then connect it to the remote machine with some protocol (vnc, rdp). Your question fills probably a long, long hoole, welcome on the HwRecs SE! :-)

Comment: There isn't really any device like this that wouldn't be connected by some sort of remote desktop network infrastructure. The latency introduced by such a setup would probably defeat the purpose of having a desktop to perform computations. I would suggest buying a portable monitor and a lightweight keyboard.

Comment: @BennettYeo I've been working at home, using my office desktop with remote desktop. While the latency is somewhat noticeable. It's easily usable as long as you're not doing time sensitive things.  OP wants a system that works in house, and with decent wi-fi the latency is easily low enough to work with and even game on if you're using the right tools.

Comment: @BennettYeo: We have USB-C monitors and we certainly can have usb keyboard and touchpad. I don't see where the latency should come from.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the Nexdock Touch could do the job for you. I don't know. Let me know if you get it. I'm curious about it myself. :)